# R- stem and leaf plot

Tags: r

I am having trouble constructing a stem and leaf plot in "R"

The data is: 1717, 1719, 1645, 3739, 3024 (This is only a subset of a larger sample but it is sufficient to show my problem)

The output I get is:

The decimal point is 3 digit(s) to the right of the |

1 | 677

2 |

2 |

3 | 0

3 | 7

This does not reconstruct my data as the numbers would be 1600, 1700...
It seems my numbers have been rounded.
I want to make the stem to be one digit as the thousands number and the leaves to be 3 digits to represent the hundreds, tens and ones.
For ex) I want to 1717 to be 1|717

And I have tried scaling but that doesn't fix my problem, How do fix this issue?

Comment: How is this different than just listing your numbers?  The point of a stem and leaf plot is to summarize.  You would need a new line for each number with what you are proposing.

Comment: But is it possible to split 4 digit numbers in a way that the stem is one digit and the leaves are all 3 digits? Because that is what the assignment wants me to do, there are way more numbers in the assignment but I just want to know how to pick the stem and leave sizes.